# Change targetName in VisualStudio 2010 setup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, setup-project, setup-deployment, file-rename

I am trying to make setup project for my application. 
[image]

I have added it to my solution with my primary application project. Everything looks fine. I can see detected dependency files:

[image]

But i must change targetName of some files.
I can't do that and I don't know the reason why?

[image]

You can see the "TargetName" is gray and unchangeable. I should be able to rename all files I want if I'm installing them on other machine.
How can I change TargetNames in my Setup Project?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's going to let you do that without renaming the .dll.  The deployment doesn't seem to allow one to change .dll names ... which makes sense, really: you've compiled with the expectation that you're going to have `Jacob.Vst.Interop.dll` as a reference, so if you remove it, and you're not installing it into the GAC, you're going to have some trouble.